# - [UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:] strange behavior

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage

In my app I make background for label with simple plain color programmatically, e.g.:

```
- (UIImage*)badgeImage
{
static UIImage *image = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(30, 20), NO, 0.0f);
    [RGB(231, 112, 63) setFill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20) cornerRadius:10] fill];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
});
return image;
```

}

Then I resize this image to needed size with `-resizableImageWithCapInsets:` and apply result as label background:

```
CGSize someSize = MY_SIZE;
UIImage *resizableImage = [badgeImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f)];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(someSize, NO, 0);
[resizableImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, someSize.width, someSize.height)];
UIImage *backImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[label setFrameSize:someSize];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backImage]];
```

But this gave me strange result:[image] I have no idea where this vertical line from and how to avoid it.

Comment: Hmmm weird... I just copied over your code and for me it works no vertical line is visible. What are your `someSize` and `size` values? And how are you initialising the UILabel?

Comment: @TamaraBernad `size` == `someSize`, it's my typo. Sure, UILabel is initialized from xib (storyboard), it's just hidden on screenshot.

Comment: I understand UILabel is initialised. I meant to say how does the initialization look like and what is the value for `someSize` to see if I can reproduce your output.

Comment: `label` has font `[UIFont systemFontWithSize:12]` and fits to it's content plus extends width by 20.
`CGSize someSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font];`
`someSize.width += 20;`
`someSize.height = MAX(size.height, resizableImage.size.height);`

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by placing `resizableImage` into `UIImageView`, that has same frame as `label`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following helped (has to be called after UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOption)

```
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), NO);
```